# Encryption via gpg: "no such file"

Tags: osx, gpg, encryption

When attempting to save some `file.gpg`, the minibuffer returns `Opening output file: Searching for program, no such file or directory, gpg`. According to the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG), all that should be required is the following two lines in ~/.emacs.d/init.el

```
(require 'epa-file)
(epa-file-enable)
```

I am running Emacs 24.5.1 on Mac OS X  10.11.6. I installed `gpg` separately via terminal command `brew install gpg`, but this did not help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a common issue with environment variables in GUI version of emacs. To solve this you can install [exec-path-from-shell package](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) and add this to your init file:

```
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

or you can modify `exec-path` by adding required folder:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/path/to/binary/folder/"))
```

Comment: With the suggested package, encryption now seems to work, but decryption does not - attempting to reopen the file yields "Decrypting /path/to/file.gpg...done\n epa-file--find-file-not-found-function: Opening input file: Decryption failed". Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: @ktolbol take a look at this answer - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27841/unable-to-decrypt-gpg-file-using-emacs-but-command-line-gpg-works

Comment: I tried those steps to no avail. I am also not convinced that the causes are the same, as in that answer, the error is "[...]Opening input file: Decryption failed, No secret key", whereas in my case, no further explanation is provided, the message simply ends at "Decryption failed, ".

Comment: Not sure why it is. Do you able to decrypt this file using gpg from terminal?

Comment: Strangely, it is working now from Emacs as well. Thanks a lot!